# Invalid read/write of size when alloc

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, alloc

So I tried to make easy alloc and then free allocated memory but valgrind writes these errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

  char* area=(char*)malloc(3);
  strcpy(area, "lal");
  printf("%s\n",area);
  free(area);

return 0;
}

Invalid write of size 4
==2728==    at 0x10873A: main (in /home/david/po1/a.out)
==2728==  Address 0x5200040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 alloc'd
==2728==    at 0x4C2CB3F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2728==    by 0x108731: main (in /home/david/po1/a.out)
==2728==
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, strings all end with the null terminator, which is a single `0x00` byte. This is automatically added to the end of all string literals, so when you copied `"lal"` into `area`, you were actually copying 4 bytes, `'l'`, `'a'`, `'l'` & `'\0'` to `area`, which is why Valgrind complained.

Always make sure you have enough room for the null terminator whenever you are dealing with C strings!

Comment: this is especially true when a string is enclosed in double quotes, such as where he did `strcpy( area, "lal" );`

Comment: `strcpy()` will actually always copy the null terminator, as it uses the null terminator to know when to stop copying! It's for this reason that using `strcpy()` is generally considered to be unsafe.

Comment: @AndrewDunn it's perfectly safe if you check the length first or otherwise know the length

Comment: @AndrewDunn  What is your preferred safer alternative to `strcpy()`?

Comment: `strcpy_s()` was added to the C standard that requires you specify the size of the destination buffer. This will ensure that extra bytes will not be written to the destination buffer if they won't fit. Generally speaking, an unchecked `strcpy()` to a buffer on the stack is game over from a security standpoint.